# godot управление башней танка

Tags: c++, 3d, godot

Смоделировал танк, пишу скрипт для башни в 3д проекте. Башня должна поворачиваться вместе с камерой. Вроде всё работает, но баги происходят. Так тут, например, при опрокидывании корпуса на бок, башня начинает вращаться с бешенной скоростью. Не понимаю как правильно написать код для такого.

```
extends Spatial
func _process(delta):
    var camera_transform = get_viewport().get_camera().global_transform
    var camera_global_z = camera_transform.basis.z.normalized()
    var object_local_z = global_transform.basis.xform(Vector3(0, 0, -1))
    var rotation_angle = atan2(camera_global_z.x, camera_global_z.z) - atan2(object_local_z.x, object_local_z.z)
    rotate(Vector3(0, 1, 0), rotation_angle)
```

Comment: не пользоваться тангенсами, а пользоваться системой векторов Связанной СК и кватернионами. При перевороте случилось схожее со складыванием рамок. Да, и во многих случаях нужна релаксация чтоб камеру не трясло до умопомрачения игрока.